# Statements have no effect

Tags: solidity, crowdsale

These entries show Statement has no Effect issues. WHy so?

```
The entries have "Statement has no Effect" problems

    startTime = _startTime; "1513683938";
    endTime = _endTime; "1513687538";
    rate = _rate; "5000";
    wallet = _wallet; "3242t536..."; // <----- sample
    token = createTokenContract();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The statements that have no effect are the ones like this:

```
"1513683938";
```

Although it's written on the same line as another statement that *does* do something (`startTime = _startTime;`), it's a separate statement, and it's just a quoted string.

I'm not sure what was intended, but a quoted string as a statement by itself doesn't have any effect.

Comment: I dont get you. The UTC timestamps are correct and I enter the values correctly: semicolon etc.

Comment: I'm saying that the line of code `"1513683938";` doesn't do anything.

Comment: why it doesn't do? it is the start date of crowdsale

Comment: I'm assuming this is your first time programming? You may want to start with something else (perhaps JavaScript) to learn the basic syntax of a programming language before diving into Solidity.

Comment: relax mate. why dont just provide correct way of writing it?

Comment: I'm quite relaxed. :-) My suggestion was meant to be a helpful one.

Comment: @Buzzmuzz5 Yeah, I agree with smarx, you should probably learn another C-style language first such as JavaScript, PHP, C# or Java. Not trying to be aristocratic here, but you should have at least some prior experience when writing software that deals with money.

Comment: these contracts are not written by me. In fact, they are based on Zeppelin open source material. So I am just customizing it.
So question is - why this established contract brings such error. How to properly enter values here